# iPhone: retrieve contents of "documents" directory

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Are there any development tools to access contents of the "documents" directory on iPhone?

I'd like to access SQLITE database that was created by my application in order to fix some bugs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode, pull up Window>Organizer. Click on your phone. In the list of applications, for your applications (that you installed with Xcode) there will be a "download" button available that will pull the entire home directory for the app.